# Backup from MSSQL RDS straight to S3 bucket with error

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-backups

Good day, please can someone assist me. I am trying to backup from MSSQL RDS to S3. I have created the following:

I have created a policy with permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ksys-ew1p-oct-dbbackup/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ksys-ew1p-oct-dbbackup"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have created an IAM role using the above policy and the following "trust relationships":
`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service":  "rds.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole" }] }`

I have created the option group with a backup_restore option.

When running the following my backup script as follows:

`exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database  @source_db_name='octopus', @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::ksys-ew1p-oct-dbbackup/Backups/octopus.bak',  @overwrite_S3_backup_file=0`

I get the error:

[2022-03-09 12:46:22.053] Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup. [2022-03-09 12:46:22.057] Task has been aborted [2022-03-09 12:46:22.060] Error making request with Error Code MovedPermanently and Http Status Code MovedPermanently. No further error information was returned by the service.

Please help me

Comment: Are you using an AWS SDK to perform this use case? For example, you could write this an a LAMBDA function using a supported programming language that reads your RDS data, creates something like JSON and then places that into an Amazon S3 bucket. Then you could take this further by running your Lambda on a schedule so you keep backing up RDS data

Comment: Is the S3 bucket in the same region as your RDS instance? _You can't back up to, or restore from, an Amazon S3 bucket in a different AWS Region from your Amazon RDS DB instance._ REF: [Limitations and recommendations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Limitations)

Comment: I will check this out thanks, it is not in the same region, I will keep you up to date

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I think I need to give some permissions on the bucket itself, I created one in the same region but now getting this:   [2022-03-10 06:51:22.090] Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup. [2022-03-10 06:51:22.090] Task has been aborted [2022-03-10 06:51:22.097] Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was returned by the service.